# Do the ducks/waterfowls in The Sopranos have any other significance apart from representing Tony's family?

Tags: analysis, the-sopranos

The waterfowls in *The Sopranos*, which Tony refers to as ducks, are introduced in the pilot of the series. Tony has a panic attack and after seeing doctor Melfi and he learns that the ducks leaving are symbolic for Tony's dread of losing his own family. The family of ducks is also seen in the episode "college". Do the ducks have any other significance in the show apart from this?

Comment: ["It's possible that Tony's fear was not that he ***would*** lose his family but that he ***should*** lose his family. Tony knows “those goddamned ducks” have to leave and are better off migrating and growing outside the confines of his yard, but this is no consolation to the deeply possessive Tony."](https://screenrant.com/sopranos-tony-ducks-meaning-family-symbol/)

Comment: What makes you question that they are ducks - they're mallards. Definitely ducks. World's most common species.